# Compare multiple values in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bioinformatics

What is the best way to find the longest transcript for each gene in a file?

I have a file with below content:

```
Gene            Transcript      Transcript's size
NONDMEG000107   NONDMET000231   329
NONDMEG000107   NONDMET000234   21
NONDMEG000107   NONDMET000235   131
NONDMEG000107   NONHSAT000018   283
NONHSAG000008   NONHSAT000019   322
NONHSAG000008   NONHSAT000020   1300
NONHSAG000008   NONHSAT000021   971
NONHSAG000008   NONHSAT000022   277
NONHSAG000008   NONHSAT000043   335
NONHSAG000008   NONHSAT000044   179
```

The output should be:

```
NONDMEG000107   NONDMET000231   329    
NONHSAG000008   NONHSAT000020   1300
```

Comment: Post input, not screenshots of input

Comment: Iterate and keep track of the largest's data.

Comment: Where is the gene? Do you mean strings? Are they any different from strings? Explain what a transcript is. This is not a biology community.

Comment: @AdrianCarr The comment you're mentioning is a very important one. In bioinformatics it's vital to know the specifics. Think codons etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear what datatypes are there, but assuming each entry is an array of gen(string), transcript(string), and size(integer):

```
data = [
  ['NONDMEG000107', 'some transcript', 10],
  ['NONDMEG000107', 'some transcript', 3229],
  ['NONDMEG000107', 'some transcript', 312],
  ['NONDMEG000107', 'some transcript', 144],
  ['NONHSAG000008', 'some transcript', 1],
  ['NONHSAG000008', 'some transcript', 345],
  ['NONHSAG000008', 'some transcript', 100],
  ['NONHSAG000008', 'some transcript', 324]
]

data.group_by(&:first).map{|_,v| v.max_by(&:last)}
#=> [["NONDMEG000107", "some transcript", 3229], ["NONHSAG000008", "some transcript", 345]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file as `CSV`, and then inspect each row and figure out which gene has maximum transcription size.  There is one change needed in input file, the header should be

```
Gene            Transcript      Transcript_size
```

Here is code:

```
require "csv"
require "pp"
hash = {}
CSV.foreach("/path/to/gene_data_file", :col_sep => " ", :headers => :first_row) do |row|
    hash[row["Gene"]] = {} if not hash[row["Gene"]]
    hash[row["Gene"]]["Transcript"] = "" if not hash[row["Gene"]]["Transcript"]
    hash[row["Gene"]]["Transcript_size"] = 0 if not hash[row["Gene"]]["Transcript_size"]

    if row["Transcript_size"].to_i > hash[row["Gene"]]["Transcript_size"]
        hash[row["Gene"]]["Transcript"] = row["Transcript"]
        hash[row["Gene"]]["Transcript_size"] = row["Transcript_size"].to_i
    end
end
pp hash
#=> {"NONDMEG000107"=>{"Transcript"=>"NONDMET000231", "Transcript_size"=>329},
#    "NONHSAG000008"=>{"Transcript"=>"NONHSAT000020", "Transcript_size"=>1300}}
```